# how to create Gsp tag by Markupbuilder?

Tags: groovy, tags, markupbuilder

I want to create a gsp file like this:

but I fail to find how to write the code by markupbuilder.

my code like this:
        MarkupBuilder mb  = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder(strXml);

```
    def builderA = new StreamingMarkupBuilder()
    def gsp = builderA.bind{
        html{
            g.uploadForm(action:"saveDataItem"){
                table{
                    f.with{
                        tr{
                            td{
                                "Test"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    println XmlUtil.serialize(gsp)
```

It dos not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
import groovy.xml.*

def mb = new StreamingMarkupBuilder()
def gsp = mb.bind {
    html{
        "g:uploadForm"(action:"saveDataItem"){
            table{
                tr{
                    td("Test")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

println gsp.toString()
```